# How to read and modify the contents of any page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is my first app so please pardon my lack of knowledge. As a demo app i would like to achieve the following things :

Stage 1 :

1 Read the contents of a page

2 Look for a regex match in the contents of that page

3 Replace them with something else

Stage 2 :

1 On submitting () text to a web page

2 Read the text that's about to get submitted

3 Look for a regex and replace it .

Could some one point in the direction of a similar app or make a small guide ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html - "Use the `chrome.webRequest` module to intercept, block, or modify requests in-flight and to observe and analyze traffic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you need to insert a Content Script, the only way to access the page's content.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

You can make a content script only extension to begin, but for more advanced extensions you should read about programmatic injection.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

From a content script you can access the page's DOM, and add listener to events in the usual way.  For example, you can use document.getElementById() or element.addListener() .

There are many ways to look for a regexp, it depends the way you want to search the page, for example yo can use

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(...);
```

Rob W gave you a nice hint to intercept submitting text with 
    chrome.webRequest